# error:that the header files are not present in the library files of STM32f0 standard peripheral driver files

Tags: embedded, stm32f0

I installed the STM32F0 stand_perip driver library and I wanted to add the driver files to my project on keil software. I did include the header and C files of the STM32F0 stand_perip driver library but this error popped that many header files are not present. like these:
#include "stm32f0xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_rcc.h"

Any leads will help?

Comment: How do you compile the project? Are you using a Makefile?

Comment: I am using the build option available in keil

Comment: The build option uses either a makefile or a preconfigured project file. Check that because most probably you have not configured the header and library path.

Comment: I included the paths in the target options for the header files present in the driver folder and the errors have reduced.but I am facing this error now : Undefined symbol assert_param (referred from stm32f0xx_gpio.o).

Comment: how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to do the same for the library paths.

Comment: I did that . now its showing this error:.\Objects\First_proj.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol assert_param (referred from stm32f0xx_adc.o).

Comment: You need to be sure that all the libraries you use are compiled when linking your program. This is somehow not happening, but without more info I can't help you. Check the log, check your paths